# Why does for-each with if-condition select all instead of specific node's attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, rdf, rdf-xml

EDIT: I found a solution that works for me (and it is indeed better to change the RDF syntax, as Conal Tuohy suggested):

```
<xsl:variable name="all_rels_comparable" select="$all/relations/rel[@name = 'is_comparable_to']"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$all_rels_comparable[@from = $id_lexUnit]">
    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="blabla/is_comparable_to/{./@to}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am consolidating information from various XML-files into a single RDF-XML file.
I always run out of memory when I try to retrieve a single node as it somehow iterates over many more nodes than intended. The line `<xsl:value-of select="$all/relations/rel/@to"/>` is the problem here, I guess. What would be the correct way to do it?

This is my xsl script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <rdf:RDF 
        xmlns:bla="blabla"
        xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
        xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

        
        <xsl:variable name="all" select="collection('./?select=*.xml')"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$all/sets/singleSet/unit">

            <xsl:variable name="id_unit" select="./@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="uri_unit">
                <xsl:copy-of select="concat('https://blabla/', $id_unit)" />
            </xsl:variable>

            <NamedIndividual rdf:about="{$uri_unit}">
                
                <bla:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
                </bla:identifier>
                
                <!-- THIS PART DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED: -->
                <xsl:if test="(($all/relations/rel/@name = 'is_comparable_to') and ($all/relations/rel/@from = $id_unit))">
                    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="blabla/is_comparable_to">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$all/relations/rel/@to"/>
                    </bla:is_comparable_to>
                </xsl:if>

            </NamedIndividual>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </rdf:RDF>
    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the file where I try to get only the last lines value of 'to':

```
<relations>
<rel name="has_user" from="28" to="45" dir="one" />
<rel name="is_part_of" from="22" to="90" dir="one" />
<rel name="is_comparable_to" from="55" to="36" dir="one" />
<rel name="is_comparable_to" from="11" to="40" dir="one" />
</relations>
```

so this is the output I intend to get:

```
<NamedIndividual rdf:about="https://blabla/11">
    <bla:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">11</bla:identifier>
    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="blabla/is_comparable_to">40</bla:is_comparable_to>
</NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  --- Hint: you test returns true when there is at least one `rel` that satisfies the condition. That's how the comparison of a node-set to a string is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans). If you want to test a specific one, then you need to change your test. I cannot tell you how, because I don't see the entire picture.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
<xsl:for-each select="$all/sets/singleSet/unit">
```

and within the body you have several path expressions beginning with `$all/relations`

Is `relations` a child element of `unit` perhaps? At any rate, it seems very odd to be doing a selection starting at `$all` when you are currently processing elements several levels down from `$all`. But without seeing what the overall XML looks like, we can't see how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that within your `xsl:for-each` you are searching the `relations` looking for `rel` elements which connect your current `unit` to some other `unit`. If I've understood it correctly, you should use something like this, in place of your `xsl:if` block:

```xml
<xsl:for-each test="$all/relations/rel[@from = $id_unit][@name = 'is_comparable_to']">
    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="blabla/is_comparable_to">
        <xsl:value-of select="@to"/>
    </bla:is_comparable_to>
</xsl:if>
```

But also, in your example the RDF/XML syntax for expressing that `is_comparable_to` property is confused. I think maybe you intend to model the relationship between units (`bla:is_comparable_to`) as an RDF Object Property? i.e.

```xml
<xsl:for-each test="$all/relations/rel[@from = $id_unit][@name = 'is_comparable_to']">
    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="https://blabla/{@to}"/>
</xsl:if>
```

... yielding:

```xml
<NamedIndividual rdf:about="https://blabla/11">
    <bla:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">11</bla:identifier>
    <bla:is_comparable_to rdf:resource="https://blabla/40"/>
</NamedIndividual>
```